# Countif without converting TEXT to NUMBER

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to set a macro, that will compare multiple lists, create a cross-table with unique values and display how many times the value is present in each list.

I'm doing OK, with one exception. When using `Countif(s)` formula `=COUNTIFS(Source!$A$2:$A$5;[@Values])`, it internaly converts "Text numbers" (e.g. 001, 00000002) into Numbers (e.g. 1, 2). I would like to avoid this behaviour and search for EXACTLY the same value, without converting.

Example data:

```
List1      List2
1          0001
0001
2
00000002
```

**What I'm getting right now (WRONG):**

[image: CompareListsWrong]

**What I want to get (EXPECTED):**
[image: CompareListsExpected]

**My question:**
How can I count EXACTLY the values in the list, without internaly converting "Text numbers" to Numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with simple UDF.

```
Function countifsExact(criteria_range As Range, criteria As String) As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In criteria_range
        If cell = criteria Then
            countifsExact = countifsExact + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

**EDIT1**:
I made another version of the UDF using some of the advice given in [Writing efficient VBA UDFs (Part 1) by Charles Williams](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/) and in [Writing efficient VBA UDFs (Part 2) by Charles Williams](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-2/).
Mainly:

- Storing the criteria_range once in a Variant variable avoiding a large overhead each time a VBA program transfers data from an Excel cell to a VBA variable
- Using Range.Value2 property, instead of Range.Value
- Using excel MATCH function to get a starting point in the sorted range, with exit on value change.

**EDIT2**:
Yet a much better solution is to use the SUMPRODUCT formula as such:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(EXACT(Source!$A$2:$A$5;[@Values])))
```

Answer (score 1):

This array formula could be suitable for you:

```
=MIN(SUMPRODUCT(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$5)=LEN(Table1[@Values]),1,0)),SUMPRODUCT(IF($A$2:$A$5=Table1[@Values],1,0)))
```

Put and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. In `Table1[@Values]`, `Table1` is your table name.

Comment: Thank you for your formula. I went with VBA solution.